# Windows Explorer lags horrifically

Tags: windows-10, performance, windows-explorer

I am running Windows 10, installed on an SSD.

The Windows Explorer process seems to require a refresh in order to update changes whenever I:

- create a new file (need to refresh for the new file to appear)
- rename a file (refresh needed)
- move files (refresh needed)

Additionally, whenever I open a file-upload dialog on any web-browser my **entire** system hangs for a few seconds even if I don't upload a file (i.e.: I press Cancel / Close)

I have tried to debug it by killing processes one by one but I cannot find the culprit.

This was not an issue a few months ago. Could it be to do with overclocking my CPU?

**Info on my system:**

```
Windows 10
Version 1909 (OS Build 18363.778)
-------------
Intel i5-6600K overclocked to 4.2GHz
8GB RAM
GTX 1070

SSD: 40.8GB free of 231GB
Hard drive: 163GB free of 931GB
```

More info

- 3.7 / 7.9GB RAM usage when idling
- 10% CPU utilization when idling
- Page file size: `Total paging file size for all drives: 11776MB`

Comment: The overclocking could be a factor if it leads to thermal throttling, in which case your CPU will clock down dramatically to prevent overheating. How much free RAM do you have when your PC is idling? How much free space on your SSD? The size of your pagefile(s)? We need more info.

Comment: I added the info you requested. Let me know if you need anything else. I don't think it is a thermal throttling issue because it occurs when idling. My temps are at ~30C when idling.

Comment: Using almost 4GB of RAM when idling is a bit on the high side, IMO. One thing you can try to limit your overhead by reducing the number of svchost processes is to open Regedit, navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control, locate an entry called SvcHostSplitThresholdInKB and change its value to 8388608, since you have 8GB of RAM installed on your PC (correct me if I'm wrong). Disable Fast Startup in Control Panel under System / Power options, and restart your PC. Check if the sluggishness is gone. Might not suffice, but it's easy to revert to the old settings if it doesn't.